# JDBC:ODBC:Access "search key was not found in any record"

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, odbc, dbf

I have a Java Application that uses the JDBC:ODBC bridge for a connection with DBF Files linked to a Microsoft Access Database (thus, I'm using the driver for a connection to a Microsoft Access Database)

There is a table named SALFAC, that contains the following fields: NRO_FAC, COD_ITE, CAN_ITE, PRC_ITE and DSC_ITE among other columns. When I perform the following query: `SELECT NRO_FAC, COD_ITE, CAN_ITE, PRC_ITE, DSC_ITE FROM SALFAC`, without a `WHERE` clause it works fine. But when I execute the following: `SELECT NRO_FAC, COD_ITE, CAN_ITE, PRC_ITE and DSC_ITE WHERE NRO_FAC=151407`, my program throws a `SQLException` with the message `The search key was not found in any record`.

The NRO_FAC column is an integer type column, so using quotes results in a syntax error.

I compacted and repaired the entire database with no avail. Also, I tested the query directly on Microsoft Access 2010 and it gave me the same error. Yesterday I tested with another JDBC:ODBC bridge to the DBF files directly and also gave me the same error with the same query.

There is no blank spaces on the tables names and the columns names.

¿Is there any additional step to do in order to make queries like these work? I need execute the query with the `WHERE` clause. Also, for each DBF file is a NTX file. Must I do something with these files as well?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I found something yesterday that might help. I changed the way I search the rows by inserting the entire DBF table content in an MS-Access temporary table, row by row, and then execute the query in the temprary table. It inserted the first 9 rows correctly, but the 10th row was next to a row that is marked as deleted and then the query crashed. Does the "marked-as-deleted" rows affect a query in MS-Access and/or dBase? If it does, is it possible ignore the "marked-as-deleted" rows using the JDBC:ODBC bridge? Also, must I install the Clipper commands (like `DBU` or `PACK`) in the server (it doesn't have them)?

Comment: *"I tested the query directly on Microsoft Access 2010 and it gave me the same error."* - So this is really an MS Access issue, not a JDBC issue, right?

Comment: Yes... i am a newbie in Stack Overflow, so i don't know where post this question.